# Reconstrain width of a UIButton

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, autolayout

I am using autolayout constraints programmatically and I would like to reset the width of my button based on its changing title.  Assuming I don't have a reference to the old width constraint that was set up on it, how can I reconstrain its width?  It seems to me that creating a new width constraint doesn't work -- I need to deactivate old one, and then activate new one.  But I don't have a reference to the old one.

```
// adding a new constraint
myButton.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(myNewWidth).active = true
```

Comment: Why don't you have a reference to the old width constraint?  By default a buttons width will hug its content, so maybe you don't even need a width constraint at all.  Set the horizontal center, and perhaps a maximum width

Comment: I'm trying to write a generic method that reconstrains a parameter, in this case a UIButton.  Would be nice to query for all constraints on an anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Create a NSLayoutConstraint property in your class. When you programatically set the width constraint of your button, assign this property the new constraint.

Then when you need to update the constraint just do this

```
myWidthConstraint.constant = newValue
```

Comment: I agree that keeping a reference to the constraint is useful, but it would be preferrable to query for a constraint on a width anchor, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one. i have not tried yet. First you need bunch of constraint filtered or all to loop through and find the required one. For that you can use this.

```
var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint! = nil
let constraints = myButton.constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis(UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal)
```

or this will get your all constraints.

```
var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint! = nil
```

Then you need to loop through them and find the required one like this.

```
for const in myButton.constraints {
    if const.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Width {
        constraint = const 
        break
    }
}
```

First attribute of width constraint always sets as "Width" and also you can put additional check like below for the item on which the constraint is applied with the if clause

```
const.firstItem as! NSObject == myButton
```

because first item of the width constraint is itself.
try if works. And if you find it, i suggest remove the specific constraint and add new one. To add width constraint on a item below is the code. Suppose width you want is 50 px.

```
myButton.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50.0))
```

This is the right approach. Don't activate or deactivate it.